# Can I change the "being" into "is" in the sentence "This layout poses many dangers for the historian, not the least of which being...."

Tags: grammar, style

> This layout poses many dangers for the serious historian, not the
>   least of which ***being*** the scornful reception that academics -
>   motivated partly by snobbish elitism but also by genuine concern over
>   scholarly standard - generally reserve for books apparently aimed at
>   the popular market.

To my understanding, this sentence means that the layout may cause dangers to the serious historian, especially the scornful receptions from other academics. I am wondering if I can change the sentence into something like:

> This layout poses many dangers for the serious historian, among which
>   not the least ***is*** the scornful reception reserved for books aimed at
>   the popular market.

Is "is" grammatically correct in the sentence I put forward? Is not, why "being" would be grammatically correct? Also, why does the author put "not the least" in front of "of which"?

Comment: In my opinion it would be _better_  as 'not the least of which is'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The resulting sentences will have different structures, but the same meaning.

A participial clause used like that is called an *absolute* clause, and is a rather literary device: most people would not use such a structure in speech. It gives more detail about something in the sentence, or some background to the sentence.

In this case it is saying more about the dangers.

Putting *not the least* before *of which* is again a somewhat literary style (as it the litotes in the phrase "not the least" itself). "Of which not the least" would be grammatical, but a bit awkward.